# How is lapping slurry made?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, synthesis

I've recently gained an interest in the whole topic of lapping and the creation of flat surfaces.
Lapping is done in different ways, but the one I'm interested in is essentially just rubbing 2 surfaces together with an abrasive in the middle. The slurry is a liquid with the very tiny abrasive particles suspended in it (usually things like diamond, aluminium oxide, silicon carbide, etc..).
These particles can be different sizes of course, for example 1/4 micron or 9 microns. And they can make this slurry to these "tolerances".

A layman such as me looking at their cheap prices is lead to believe that maybe this isn't such a complicated manufacturing process. I don't know much about chemistry, but I am mighty curious about this.

How are these big batches of really tiny abrasive particles made to within such a small tolerance for cheap? Thank you!

Comment: I guess they get particles of all sizes, then fraction them by sedimentation speed.

Comment: The abrasive substance is synthesized or mined (e.g., garnet), then pulverized or ground up, then size sorted via sieves, etc.

Comment: Pretty much exactly as they make different grades of sandpaper.

Comment: Adding to the question: why are various lanthanide oxides used for lapping glass, in preference to other abrasives? See http://sfsidewalkastronomers.org/index.php?page=notes-from-john-dobson-s-telescope-making-class

Comment: @EdV are sub-micron sieves really that easy to come by? And how do you pulverize or grind diamond?

Comment: @TrisT Sieves are for the bigger stuff. As Ivan noted, sedimentation (like field flow fractionation) can be used for smaller sizes. Small size synthetic diamonds are prepared as such: no need to crush bigger ones!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Well, I have the ceria, and a fair number of other abrasives, e.g., zirconium diboride, but I would never try making my own Dobsonian telescope mirror! Those folks are wild! But thanks for the link!

Comment: @EdV so you synthesize for example diamonds, and that process makes little diamonds of all shapes and sizes, so then you just sort them. I just looked up this FFF process, it it's pretty genius, never would have guessed sedimentation could take that form so thank you for clarifying that too. This is a lot of stuff that I can search further and actually get results on, thank you!